# No me funcionan los clics hacia otros elementos de mi página (ancla)

Tags: php, jquery, css, html5

No puedo lograr que al hacer clic en una serie de botones (en donde cada uno tienen todas las letras del abecedario y que están dentro de un div de manera fija) me lleve al ancla que está en diferentes `<h2 id="x">` (donde la "x" sería cada una de las distintas letras "A", "B", "C"…."Z").

Creo que el problema está en el archivo `.php` es que aquí donde voy armando todo el contenido de la página. En esta página pongo todas las palabras que por ejemplo empiezan con la letra "A" (la búsqueda se hace en mi base de datos con un bucle) y donde también aprovecho a poner de título (el `<h2>`) que desde `php` tengo así: `echo "<h2 id='$Let'>".$Let."</h2>";` (**es aquí donde quiero que vaya cuando se pulsa el botón de algunas de las letras**).

Les pongo la parte del código de `php` (**Enlaces.php**) el cual es una función que es donde tengo el `"<h2>"` con su `id`:

```
<?php
$Let="";
$Sep="";
$Sel=0;
$Band=0;
$Comp='/[^A-Z]/';
function Todas($cxn,$Let,$Band,$Comp,$Sep){
     $sql = mysqli_query($cxn, "select Palabra from….");
     $CarA = array("Á","Å","É","Í","Ó","Ú");
     $CarS = array("A","A","E","I","O","U");
     while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {   
          $Ter=$row['Palabra'];
          $Ter = str_replace($CarA,$CarS,$Ter);
        if (preg_match($Comp,ucfirst($Ter[0]))) {
            if($Band==0){
                echo "<h2 style='margin:0 0 0 0;border-bottom:#930 solid 1px'></h2>";
                $Band=1;
            }else{
                $Sep="<span class='bd'> • </span>";
                 }
        } else {  
            if (ucfirst($Ter[0])!==ucfirst($Let)){
                $Let=$Ter[0];
                if ($Let=='A') {
                    echo "<h2 id='$Let' style='margin:0.8em 0 0 0;border-bottom:#930 solid 1px'>".$Let."</h2>";
                    $Sep="";
                }else{
                    $Sep="";
                    echo "<h2 id='$Let' style='margin:0.8em 0 0 0;border-bottom:#930 solid 1px'>".$Let."</h2>";
                }
            }else{$Sep="<span class='bd'> • </span>";}
        }
         echo $Sep;?>
        <a class="GloIT" href="./<?php echo $row['Palabra'];?>" title="<?php echo $row['Palabra']; ?>"><?php echo $row['Palabra'];?></a>
    <?php
    } // end while 
} //end function todas  
?>
```

Luego en la página principal (**Contenido.html**) tengo el `div` en donde se va a mostrar todo el contenido que viene de `php` (es el `<div class="Secc"`>). En esta página principal hago uso de `JQuery` y de `Ajax`. Dentro de `JQuery` tengo la creación de los botones (la del div fijo) con un `for` para ir poniendo cada letra en una lista (`<li><a href="#${letra}">${letra}</a></li>`).

Acá pueden ver parte del [Código](https://codepen.io/DamianMDQ/pen/wbgBbx) (también hago unos comentarios ahí). Allí cierta parte de `HTML` lo tuve que poner a mano (porque en realidad todo lo que está dentro del `<div class="Secc">` lo cargo desde `php` como pueden ver en el `JQuery` con su `ajax`). Claro que ahí funcionan los clics. Al seleccionar (en el ejemplo de la A a la F) me lleva a los `<h2>` correspondientes.

Será cuestión de que **no lo tengo todo en un único archivo**. Es que ayer se me dio por poner todo en un solo archivo y anduvo el ancla. Pero no quiero hacerlo así, además de esta manera otras cosas no me funcionan.

Lo raro es que si quiero inspeccionar los elementos de mi página veo que están los `<h2>` con sus correspondientes `id` (A, B, C, D…Z). Cualquier cosa hay como un seguimiento en el [Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93676/discussion-between-damian-garcia-and-enxaneta) por si me queiren consultar algo más.

Answer (score -1):

Es probablemente, porque en el href te falta el hash antes de la variable, de forma que queda `href='#variable'`

Comment: ¿En dónde no está? Quizás no has visto el código que pongo aparte. Allí en la parte de JQuery está el `<li><a href="#${letra}">${letra}</a></li>` quedando por ejemplo (<a href="#A">A</a>).

Comment: disculpa jaja, vi el primer código y parecia clarisimo asique ignoré lo demas.De hecho al entrar al codepen a mi si me funciona el código, y salta al punto que corresponde. Pero obviamente tiene que haber suficiente contenido para que permita scrollear, capaz es algo con tu navegador.

Comment: Y claro ahí funciona porque toda la parte del **<h2>** la hice, como ya comente, a mano en html. Pero la realidad es que ese contenido viene todo de la página de **php**.

Comment: que codigo te tira el inspector de elementos al hacerlos con php? aparece bien el id y el enlace con el href?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]

Comment: @FacundoBranbate Si, como ya comente al final de todo. Al hacer clic derecho y poner "inspeccionar elemento" veo que los `id` los carga bien en los distintos **<h2>** (<h2 id="A">, <h2 id="B">, <h2 id="C">...)